# Unable to Associate a SB Queue to an Azure IOT Hub Custom Route

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to add a Custom Endpoint to an IOT Hub.  The Endpoint should write to a Service Bus Queue in my Resource Group.  I'm getting error `"No namespaces found for subscription id ... in the region where this IoT hub is located"`.

According to the IoT Hub Properties blade on the Portal, my IoT Hub is in my Resource Group xxx, in the East US region location.  My IoT Hub has 3 built-in endpoints:  File Upload Notifications (`messages/servicebound/fileNotifications`), Cloud to device feedback (`messages/servicebound/feedback`) and Events (`messages/events`).

According to the ServiceBus Properties blade, my ServiceBus namespace is also in my Resource Group xxx, also located in the East US location. My ServiceBus has several Queues and Topics.  Some of my queues enable partitioning, others do not.  The max size of my queues range from 1GB to 16 GG to 80 GB.  They are all active.

I've also tried to create a new EventHub namespace, with an Event Hub instance, in my Resource Group xxx, also located in the East US location.  The IoT Hub Custom Route blade also does not see this Event Hub's namespace.

What am I missing?  Is the Custom Endpoints feature requiring something of my IoT Hub or ServiceBus or EventHub that I'm not setting properly?

Comment: Are they in the same subscription id?

Comment: What about a custom endpoint to the Storage Container? Can you create it?

Comment: They are in the same SubscriptionId, same ResourceGroup, same Data Center.  I was able to create a custom endpoint for the Storage Container.

Comment: Are you using an Azure Portal IoTHub/Endpoints/Add for adding a custom endpoint to the IoT Hub? When you selected an Endpoint type = Event Hub, can you see your Event Hub namespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an Azure issue, now fixed by Microsoft.

The IOT Hub and SB were correct, as far as the Portal UI was concerned.  In our case the scripts all used the same, precise, string for specifying Location but the issue occurred nonetheless.

There had been an issue in the SubscriptionId/ResourceGroup/Location validation logic in Azure - I believe due to how the 'Location' element was stored internally originally.

I'm told that Microsoft has repaired the data -- potentially Azure wide, but certainly the data that affected our Subscriptions and their IotHubs.